# Increase/test speed of my magento website

Tags: performance, magento, testing

Lately i have experienced something strange on my magento site. Sometimes my site is running slow and sometimes its acceptable.

Do you know some tools to test it a day long?My site is running on a VPS.

http://bit.ly/iefbw1

Love to know your results and reviews on the sites speed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To test the speed of a website + immediately get recommendations on what can be easily improved to reduce the loading time I use [GTMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/).

Some other pointers for speeding up Magento:

- Install [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) on your VPS + [PageCache powered by Varnish](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pagecache-powered-by-varnish.html)
  (Magento module)
- Install APC for better caching
- Make sure you have enabled [Magento's default compilation feature](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_compiler/process/index)

**EDIT:** As mentioned by ADM you must also optimize your MySQL and Apache (considering you are running apache2) configuration.

**EDIT2:** As general suggestion I suggest you to Google for "speed up Magento" and you will find hundreds of topics/articles covering this subject.

Answer (score -1):

@Kenny you have a bit wrong approach, to start you have to check your apache config, unload all extra modules `apache2ctl -M`, same with `php -m`, then install apc or eaccelerator, then check your mysql config, it usually takes 2 days to see mysql real values, use [mysqlreport](http://hackmysql.com/scripts/mysqlreport) perl script, it will show you whats going on with your database. then you go for [Leverage browser caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching), and only after you setup [FPC](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/i-speed-performance-booster.html). not sure if compilation 'must have' feature...

Comment: I only responded with what I would do. The suggestion I gave are quick-wins and IMO they need to be done by everyone running a Magento shop as there will be a huge decrease in page loading time. (Especially because of Varnish. Covering the basics like apache2 and MySQL configuration are a must of course but aren't they supposed to be optimized with any website? I merely pointed out the Magento specific ones ;)

Comment: Thanks for the replies got lots of good new ways to speed it up ;)
I knew that magento was not very speedy but sometimes its frustrating to see how slow it runs. I had ezapps installed first but that didn't works so well, in fact it made a mess of it.

Comment: Another 'thing' i found out was that if you run ioncube on the site that it slow downs with 60 - 80%!! Thats massive! One more thing i faced is the iowait on my VPS, do you know what i can do about that?

Comment: huge percentage on IO means that your storage system is dead, either they have old SATA drives, bad RAID, etc. in average test your IO should stay at about 5%-8% and drive speed must be 80-250mb/s, if it`s going lower than 20%-40% and drive speed 20-40mb/s, you better move to another hosting.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked many Magento websites and find that most of them are very slow.
Have you ever checked why the Magento websites are very Slow. Let me show some reasons and the solution for making Magento Websites Faster.
Reasons why Magento websites are slower

1. Compilation Turned Off
2. Cache Problem
3. No Full Page Cache
4. Code looping
5. Flat Data not Enabled
6. Large Database
7. Memory Limit Too Low
8. Indexes are not updated
9. Not Using Memcached
10. Merge css and js files
11. Magento Htaccess Gzip, Mod_deflate, Performance Settings
12. Server

Solutions for Making Magento websites Faster
1. Compilation Turned Off : The Main reason due to the Installation of many modules.All activities of the system must go through modules and an action in Magento may involve some modules, thus the loading and running of Magento system are quite slow. So if you want to make your website faster then first enable the compilation.
Procedure for enabling the compilation
Login to the Admin panel
System -> Tools -> Compilation
-> Then Click on the Run Compilation Process

2. Cache Problem : Cache is not enabled in your system.
   Procedure for enabling the Cache
   System ->Cache Management
   -> Select All -> then from action select options -> select Enable ->click Submit
3. No Full Page Cache : Full page cache is very important for any Magento based websites.
   You can also use this free Magento extension for Full page Cache.
   Lesti Full PAge Cache
4. Code looping : Their might be a reason for the Custom Code, may be some wrong code added so that it is looping and using the wrong code and looping database queries. If this is the problem then any developer can only solve the problem or use the default code.
5. Flat Data not Enabled : Flat Category and product data is very important for Magento Websites. Whether or not you should enable the Flat Data of Products and/or Categories varies depending on your Magento website structure.
   If you have only dozens of products with many attributes, or have a few hundred products with only a few attributes/attribute variations, then flattening the products/categories may not impact the site speed significantly. On the other hand, if your website contained almost 1,000, or possibly several thousands of products, then it is almost always recommended to flatten your products. If these products are spread across multiple dozens of categories (and products aren’t duplicated across these categories), then flattening these categories would be suggested as well.

System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Then in frontend tab you will find two settings as
Use flat catalog category and flat catalog product. Enables both the settings to yes.

6. Large Database : Due to large database size might decrease the performance of your server. So it is always recommended that you backup and delete the old and garbage data. If you have log enabled then what changes you will do every time in the Admin it will be stored ion the Admin, so if it is not necessary then either you can off the the record of the log or make the setting as it will delete all you logs at the end of the day or at the end of the week. if you have more than 1000 of visitors per day in your website then certainly it saved all the searched data in the database and other customer related info, if it is not so important then you can also delete and clean your database.

Procedure for enabling or disabling the logs in Magento
System -> Configuration -> Developer – > Click on log settings tab
Here you will find the setting for the log

7. Memory Limit Too Low : I have checked in some posts, they are saying that this may also be the reason and it should be improved to make Magento website faster.
   There is a setting in your configuration files which sets the maximum amount of memory you can dedicate to PHP processes. Since Magento is a big memory hog, having this value be greater than 128mB can significantly bump up the time it takes Magento to perform operations.

what you are trying to do.

For more info about : Increasing Magento Speed and Loading Time

http://www.webtechnologycodes.com/increasing-magento-speed-and-loading-time/